# Command Line Options for OpenVPNConnect.exe (3.2.2)

Tags: windows, openvpn

I am trying to up/down my VPN connection through command line / powershell.
I have googled extensively, but cannot find any recent information about the command line parameters.
I have tried the suggestions on stack:

```
.\OpenVPNConnect.exe --config <name of ovpn file>
.\OpenVPNConnect.exe --connect <name of ovpn file>
.\OpenVPNConnect.exe --connect <full path of ovpn file>
.\OpenVPNConnect.exe --connect <name of profile>
```

but I have no dice, the gui opens but it does not connect, it looks like the connection information available is all old. I notice that there is another application in the install folder called `ovpnconnector.exe` This seems to be a possible option, but it involves installing a service for the ovpn file, and then starting and stopping the service using service control. There must be an easy way using command line arguments documented somewhere?

> Simple Question: show do I up/down OpenVPN using the command line in the newer versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me `.\OpenVPNConnect.exe" connect "PC <name of profile>`

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/OpenVPN/comments/klnl1j/new_command_line_options_for_openvpnconnectexe/

Comment: I decided to download and install the community version - more options.

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I up/down OpenVPN using the command line in the newer versions?

**Connect**

```
openvpn-gui --connect <name of profile>
```

**Disconnect**

No easy way. You have to kill the process:

```
taskkill.exe /F /IM openvpn.exe
```

Drawback: It apparently brings up a dialog after disconnecting, expecting to click OK. That can probably be worked around.

Source: [How would you disconnect from OpenVPN through the command line on windows? : VPN](https://www.reddit.com/r/VPN/comments/5ozunt/how_would_you_disconnect_from_openvpn_through_the/)

Comment: Unfortunately this question is not a duplicate and the details above are not valid for the current version. `openvpn-gui.exe` does not exist. The files are renamed, and the command line options have clearly changed. The new exe name is `OpenVPNConnect.exe`